# Only Collects First Index

Tags: java, arrays

So I'm supposed to make a list that contains the character that follows each non-tail occurrence of a pattern in a text. The character stored at index n of the list must be the character that followed the nth non-tail occurrence of the pattern.

Ex: The test case getCharsThatFollowPattern("abcabdabcab", "ab") should return the ArrayList ['c', 'd', 'c'].

I'm having problems trying to get the list to iterate through the pattern text. I get ['a', 'a', 'a'] in my test case instead of ['c', 'd', 'c'].

```
public static ArrayList<Character> getCharsThatFollowPattern (String text, String pattern) { 

  ArrayList<Character> character = new ArrayList<Character>(); 
  int i = 0; 

  while (i < text.length()) 
  { 
    if (i < text.length()) 
    { 
      character.add(text.charAt(text.indexOf(pattern, i))); 
      i = i + text.indexOf(pattern, i) + pattern.length(); 
    } 
  } 

  return character;
}
```

Why wont it iterate through? :(

Comment: so your code is trying to isolate each character immediately after every occurrence of "ab"?

Comment: @kaan yes, then take all those isolated characters that follow the pattern and store them in an array

Comment: it's tough to find a simple explanation. the logic to calculate `i` doesn't seem right. I added a print statement - `System.out.print(i + " ");` - and got: `2 7 18`.

Comment: @kaan Interesting... It makes sense that `i` might cause problems. I think it's returning char 'a' for all the iterations because the index is only reading the first char of the pattern. I'm not sure how to make it stop reading only the first char and move on to the other parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intent is to find a substring pattern inside the larger `text` value, and then add each of those characters to an array. There are a few things going on in your code, so I tried to create the simplest example that shows how to get it to work, but exclude things that you were already fine with (like creating an array and populating values).

The code below finds where the next pattern starts – `indexOfNextPatternStart` – that would be where ever "ab" occurs next. Then it adds the length of "ab" itself to get whatever index is *after* that. So in your `text` example, it starts with `"abc"` – "ab" is clearly at the front, but you want the index of `"c"`. That's what `indexOfCharAfterPattern` contains. At that point, you've got the character isolated. In my example, I'm storing that temporarily as `charAfterPattern` and printing it out.

I added the `if (indexOfCharAfterPattern < text.length())` check to protect against the last "ab" in `text`. There's nothing after that last "ab", so trying to look ahead for the next character won't work.

```
public static void printThatFollowPattern(String text, String pattern) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < text.length()) {
        int indexOfNextPatternStart = text.indexOf(pattern, i);
        int indexOfCharAfterPattern = indexOfNextPatternStart + pattern.length();

        if (indexOfCharAfterPattern < text.length()) {
            char charAfterPattern = text.charAt(indexOfCharAfterPattern);
            System.out.println("charAfterPattern: " + charAfterPattern);
        } else {
            break;
        }

        i = indexOfCharAfterPattern + 1;
    }
}
```